# How to get the status of a SOAP request?

Tags: php, soap

Actually I'm checking the info of SOAPClient in the php documentation, but I haven't found any function to get the request status for the SOAP ex(200, 500). Does anybody know how to get the status request?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponseheaders.php may be helpful.

Comment: I've already tried but is returning NULL `var_dump($client->__getLastResponse()); `